# Apps using ACM are not allowed to have wildcard domains on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

currently I am moving my application from AWS to Heroku.
While wildcard addition I have faced a problem `Apps using ACM are not allowed to have wildcard domains`. Could you please tell me how to add wildcards? My app is on the phase of moving and  my Dynos is free of charge. Also I would like to use for staging a free of charge Dynos, because it is enough for me now.
example
my domain: bar.com
I want to this: [foo].bar.com instead `foo` may be any name

Comment: it seems they can't support wildcards for ACM due to Let's encrypt! current limitations: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/please-support-wildcard-certificates/258/7 - So the only way it seems to have ssl certificates running through subdomains is with a regular purchased wildcard SSL certificate and then setting the base domains plus wildcard domain in heroku and pointing your domain provider to heroku's ones. I did it and it's fairly simple to do, just boring and, sort of expensive, a wild card domain goes for around 45€ per year

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer To have a certificate ssl I must have add an addon to the heroku? If I have a working domain with a certificate on the `namecheap` also I must add addon ?

Comment: I think you no longer need an addon, just to add the certs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl , then configure them domains on heroku & your domain provider to point to the correct heroku targets for ssl

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer this is not working. All examples where showing how to use letsencrypt for rails app is written, that this Deprecated and recommend use ACM. ACM not support wildcard domain.

Comment: indeed, I told you in the first comment they don't support wildcards for ACM. I never used letsencrypt, but I'm sure there's other examples somewhere on the documentation because I've used it not that long ago to implement sub domain ssl on an app.

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer I have cert. But how to this working on heroku?

Comment: Actually you need the SSL addon, my bad, in my dashboard it doesn't show as having the addon so I thought you no longer need it.

Comment: but the addon paid. I would like free option

Comment: if you find out how let me know, I would like it too!

Answer (score 6):

You can generate a free Let's encrypt wildcard certificate and upload it to Heroku. You can do it by following the steps here:
http://aawaara.com/post/175058359322/generate-a-free-lets-encrypt-wildcard-ssl

```
curl https://get.acme.sh | sh
# Open a new terminal window after executing above command

# Create a cloudflare account (and assuming that you will use it for DNS) and get your API key from the profile section
export CF_Email=my.cloudflare@example.com
export CF_Key=replace_with_cloudflare_api_key

# Generate wildcard certificate for *.example.com
acme.sh  --issue -d example.com  -d '*.example.com'  --dns dns_cf
```

In case you don't use Cloudflare DNS, below is a list of other supported DNS providers:
https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh/tree/master/dnsapi#1-use-cloudflare-domain-api-to-automatically-issue-cert

Comment: how can i use this for heroku if in the settings of the app where need to add a certificate SSL I see this text: `SSL Upgrade to paid dynos to configure Heroku SSL`

Comment: Probably SSL is only available for paid dynos, and not for the free ones. Once you upgrade to paid ones, you can upload the custom certificate on heroku.

Comment: thanks. I know that. But I would like to know how can I automate this process of updating and uploading the SSL certificate to Heroku every 3 months (such a period for let'sencrypt)

Comment: May be a cron job which does that (certificate upload) every 3 months by using the Heroku platform API or the command line utility: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#manually-uploading-certificates-and-intermediaries